# Drools, CEP: Collect events that are not followed by a certain event

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, complex-event-processing

I'm using drools 7.29 in STREAM mode, and i would like to collect events that are not followed by a certain event.

```
$transaction: TransactionOmDto(service_type == "CASHOUT", transfer_status == "TS", $requestId: transfer_id, $msisdn: msisdn) over window:length(1)

not(TransactionOmDto(service_type == "CONFIRMATION", transfer_status == "TS", transfer_id == $requestId, msisdn == $msisdn, this after [0s, 5m] $transaction))

//How to collect such $transaction in a List ???
```

For example in my system, when i receive a transaction `$t1` that matches the following patterns,

```
$t1.transfer_id = "my_uniq_transfer_id"
$t1.msisdn == "07xxxxxxxx"
$t1.service_type == "CASHOUT"
$t1.transfer_status == "TS"
```

then I am also supposed to receive within the next 5 minutes another transaction `$t2` from the same POS which should meet the following conditions:

```
$t2.transfer_id = "my_uniq_transfer_id"
$t2.msisdn == "07xxxxxxxx"
$t2.service_type == "CONFIRMATION"
$t2.transfer_status == "TS"
```

Sometimes `$t2` transactions do not arrive. **And the goal of my rule is to report all `$t1` transactions that have not had their `$t2` confirmation transaction in the system.**

Comment: So you want all events which occurred in the 5 minute window before `$transation`?

Comment: hello @Roddy, NO. I want all the `$transaction` that are NOT FOLLOWED by an other `TransactionOmDto` event in the new 5 minutes, matching the given pattern i.e: <br/>`TransactionOmDto(service_type == "CONFIRMATION", transfer_status == "TS", transfer_id == $requestId, msisdn == $msisdn, this after [0s, 5m] $transaction)`.

Comment: So when you receive $transaction, you want all events in the next 5 minutes, except those that look like dto you've described? If that's not it, can you update your question with an example scenario of  received transactions and which ones you'd expect to be in your collection?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I updated the question this an example.

Comment: What should be the trigger for this rule? every time a new transaction is received?

Comment: Yes. After a certain number of transactions without confirmation, an alert is raised in the THEN parity of the rule

Answer (score 0):

Common 'heartbeat arrival problem'. Could you please check existing simplified example whether it suits your needs from [here](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert/wiki/Complex-event-processing). Please ask additional questions if any.

Rule

```
dialect 'mvel'

import TemporalReasoningTest.Heartbeat

declare Heartbeat @role (event) end

global java.io.PrintStream stdout

rule "Sound the Alarm"
when
    $h: Heartbeat() from entry-point "MonitoringStream"
    not(Heartbeat(this != $h, this after[0s,10s] $h) from entry-point "MonitoringStream")
then
    stdout.println('No heartbeat')
end
```

Model and test

```
@DroolsSession("classpath:/temporalReasoning.drl")
public class TemporalReasoningTest {
    
    public static class Heartbeat {
        public int ordinal;
        
        public Heartbeat(int ordinal) {
            this.ordinal = ordinal;
        }
    }
    
    @RegisterExtension
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        drools.setGlobal("stdout", System.out);
    }
    
    @Test
    @TestRules(expected = {})
    public void testRegularHeartbeat() {
        Heartbeat heartbeat1 = new Heartbeat(1);
        drools.insertAndFireAt("MonitoringStream", heartbeat1);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat1);
        
        Heartbeat heartbeat2 = new Heartbeat(2);
        drools.insertAndFireAt("MonitoringStream", heartbeat2);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat1, heartbeat2);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.assertDeleted(heartbeat1);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat2);
        
        Heartbeat heartbeat3 = new Heartbeat(3);
        drools.insertAndFireAt("MonitoringStream", heartbeat3);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat2, heartbeat3);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.assertDeleted(heartbeat2);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat3);
        
        Heartbeat heartbeat4 = new Heartbeat(4);
        drools.insertAndFireAt("MonitoringStream", heartbeat4);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat3, heartbeat4);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.assertDeleted(heartbeat3);
        drools.assertExist(heartbeat4);
        
        drools.assertFactsCount(1);
        assertEquals(4, drools.getObject(Heartbeat.class).ordinal);
        drools.printFacts();
    }
    
    @Test
    @TestRules(expectedCount = { "1", "Sound the Alarm" })
    public void testIrregularHeartbeat() {
        drools.insertAndFireAt("MonitoringStream", new Heartbeat(1));
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFireAt("MonitoringStream", new Heartbeat(2), new Heartbeat(3));
        drools.advanceTime(5, SECONDS);
        
        drools.assertFactsCount(2);
        drools.printFacts();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Mike. Thank you for answering. I think this rule is very similar to the one I wrote before. My problem is to know if it is possible to collect these `Heartbeat` corresponding to `$h`(`Heartbeat`which are not followed by other `Heartbeat` in 10s) in a list over time.

Comment: when rule activates, just add $h to some collection (global variable)

Comment: OK, thanks. This is what I ended up doing, since I couldn't do it just with`collect` and `accumulate` directly.